Is Contradiction/ Counterexample of/ for discontinuous function possible?
I work with the Epsilon-Delta-Defintion of Continuity: A function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continous, if $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x \in D: |x - x_0|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.
I want to show the discontinuity of the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with f(x) = 4 (if $x < 0$) and f(x) = x + 2 (if $x \geq 0$).
Of course I can negate the defintion to $\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta > 0 \exists x \in D: |x - x_0|< \delta \wedge |f(x) - f(x_0)| \geq \epsilon$ and do a direct proof.
But I think about a proof by contradiction/ Counterexample. Would it be a Counterexample, if I would structure it like this: $\exists \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \exists x \in D: |x - x_0|< \delta \wedge |f(x) - f(x_0)| \geq \epsilon$ (Having the negated defintion but with an existential quantifier for $\delta > 0$)?
And would it be a proof by contradiction like this?
Let $r > 2$. For all $\delta > 0$, let $x < 0$, so that $|x - x_0| = |x - 0| = |x| < \delta$. Futhermore $|f(x) - f(x_0)| = |4 - (0 + 2)| = |4 - 2| = 2 < r$. This is a contradiction to $r > 2$ and therefor the function is discontinuous.
Thank you for any help!

No, saying there exists a $\delta$ is meaningless here. Otherwise you could prove that every non-constant function is not continuous.

Your definition of continuity is wrong, what you defined are uniformly continuous functions.

Thank you for the answers.
